# Documentation for SLDS colour and background colour classes like slds-text-blue

Tags: slds, theme-branding

I am new to salesforce design system and I have never used CSS classes in Salesforce before. I am trying to find proper documentation for SLDS colour classes but I didn't find exact one. What I find is this [documentation](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/design-tokens/#category-sizing) which consist of Token for colour classes.

Please provide me a good reference where I can find CSS styling in LWC.

Comment: SLDS does not expose "colour classes" (naming classes like this is bad practice since CSS classes are intended to be abstractions), but instead has "[themes](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/themes/)". If you want specific colours that are not defined by a Salesforce App's branding then you need to deal with this yourself in your own CSS, potentially using [styling hooks](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/platforms/lightning/styling-hooks/) if you need to impact various components in the page.

Comment: Have you searched Trailhead for modules like [this one](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/lightning-design-system-development-for-designers/get-started-with-slds)?

Comment: I'm also looking for the equivalent of Bootstrap's `bg-primary` class, for example. The [themes documentation](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/themes/) is sorely lacking. How can I apply the primary or secondary theme color to an element such as a scoped alert?